# error 302 on submit of custom login form in Grails spring security core plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

just followed this [tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) for custom login form, but when i submit its not authenticating but redirecting back to home.

here is the configuration

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/dashboard/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/'
```

and post request going to 
http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check
status code is 302 and in response header location is http://localhost:8080/

Moreover normal /login/auth with default ui is is working fine.

I am new to grails as well as to spring security. Am i missing something? :|

versions: spring 3.0.4
grails 3.1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read changes in [v3](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/spring-security-core-3.0.4.pdf) , was looking at older tutorial. To save someone's else time

> /j_spring_security_check (the apf.filterProcessesUrl config setting)
>   changed to **/login/authenticate**
>
> /j_username (the apf.usernameParameter and
>   switchUser.usernameParameter config settings) changed to **username**
>
> /j_password (the apf.passwordParameter config setting) changed to
>   **password**
>
> /j_spring_security_logout (the logout.filterProcessesUrl config
>   setting) changed to **/logoff**
>
> In Spring Security 4 the value is actually /logout, but that conflicts
>   with the standard LogoutController url, so the plugin uses **/logoff**
>   instead
>
> _spring_security_remember_me (the rememberMe.parameter config setting) changed to **remember-me**
>
> /j_spring_security_switch_user (the switchUser.switchUserUrl config
>   setting) changed to
>   **/login/impersonate**
>
> /j_spring_security_exit_user (the switchUser.exitUserUrl config
>   setting) changed to
>   **/logout/impersonate**